# Why presence stanza is rejected when there is no "to" attribute

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

As for [XMPP documentation (Example 10)](http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc3921.html) this kind of stanza should be valid:

```
<presence from="support@im.server.com" />
```

However ejabberd replies with 400 response. The reason here is a missing "to" field. I wonder why it happens. 
[Based on a XML schema of a XEP-0114 analysis](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0114.html#schema) I guess the reason is in a fact that support@im.server.com is an external component.

Could someone confirm that I am right/wrong, or give a suggestion how to overcome the situation?

XMPP Server: ejabberd 2.1.5.

Comment: Did you try to ask the ejabbered developers about this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

example 10 which you refer to sends out a user presence to a client and includes a resource. So this is server => client.

If I understand you correct you send this presence from your component to the server (component=>server). Without a to address the server is not able to route this presence to another entity.

Comment: Indeed I were trying to send stanza from a component to a server and expected server to broadcast it to all the subscribers of my component. Happens it is not permitted by xml schema of 0114. 

As for RFC6120 section 8.2.2 (http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6120#section-8.2.2) presence stanza without "to" attribute has to be broadcasted to all the subcribers of "from". 
Thus I expected my stanza to be broadcasted. However, this is true only for a client-server communication, and not a component-server. Although there are subscribers for the component jid (support@im.server.com).